# How to connect my speakers to my computer and produce 5.1 surround audio output?

Tags: audio, motherboard, sound-card, speakers, surround-sound

So I have a Logitech X-530. There is an audio adapter in which I had the input and ouput connected (jacks and plugs connected by color). In that case I could not experience 5.1 surround audio. But I disconnected the output (the 3 plugs in blue, green and red) and connected it directly to the back of my machine. I don't think I have a sound card but my motherboard supports 5.1 audio.

[Adapter Image](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/481i0EB29CDCD05F4CF1/image-size/original?v=mpbl-1&px=-1)

So I wonder do I really need that adapter? Since it could support only 2.1 (stereo) audio. I read somewhere it is needed for game consoles but I am not sure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where did that adapter come from? Looks a bit like Logitech put it in the box so Users with a single audio jack, e.g. notebook owners, could get all speakers running. Pretty poor solution though, if you ask me.

Can you use all channels now as expected? Remember to install the latest drivers and the configure the speakers as a 5.1 system from windows' audio panel.

Comment: I did that I was just worrying not to damage my system without that adpter. Looks like I don't need it anymore.

Comment: I guess that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sound card needs to support 5.1 audio.

The software you are using needs to ALSO support 5.1 audio.

Since you did state your hardware or the software you're using, i'm assuming this is your problem.

Comment: So I won't keep the adpter connected since I get the audio output I need.